# How to add space in conditions Python

Tags: python, space

i have this code:

```
 def negate_sequence(text):
        negation = False
        delims = "?.,!:;"
        result = []
        words = text.split()
        prev = None
        pprev = None
        for word in words:
            stripped = word.strip(delims).lower()
            negated = "not " + stripped if negation else stripped
            result.append(negated)
            if any(neg in word for neg in ["not", "n't", "no"]):
                negation = not negation

            if any(c in word for c in delims):
                negation = False

        return result

    text = "i am not here right now, because i am not good to see that"
    sa = negate_sequence(text)
    print(sa)
```

well what this code do, basically his adding 'not' to the next words and he don't stop adding 'not' till he get to one of this "?.,!:;" they are like some sort of breaks for example if you run this code you'll get.

```
['i', 'am', 'not', 'not here', 'not right', 'not now', 'because', 'i', 'am', 'not', 'not good', 'not to', 'not see', 'not that']
```

what i want to do is to add the space instead of all this "?.,!:;" so if i have to run the code i will get this result instead:

```
['i', 'am', 'not', 'not here', 'right', 'now', 'because', 'i', 'am', 'not', 'not good', 'to', 'see', 'that']
```

so the code only add the 'not' to the next word only and break after finding the space, but i have tried everything but nothing worked for me please if anyone has an idea how to do that i will be appreciated . . .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: change `delims` to `" "`

Comment: no empty quotation " " doesn't work, i have tried it before thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ipsnicerous's excellent code does exactly what you want, except it misses out the very first word.  This is easily corrected by using is_negative(text[i-1] and and changing enumerate(text[1:] to enumerate(text[:] to give you:

```
def is_negative(word):
    if word in ["not", "no"] or word.endswith("n't"):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def negate_sequence(text):
    text = text.split()
    # remove punctuation
    text = [word.strip("?.,!:;") for word in text]
    # Prepend 'not' to each word if the preceeding word contains a negation.
    text = ['not '+word if is_negative(text[i-1]) else word for i, word in enumerate(text[:])]
    return text

if __name__ =="__main__":
    print(negate_sequence("i am not here right now, because i am not good to see that"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but it seems like you want to turn every negation into a double negative?

```
def is_negative(word):
    if word in ["not", "no"] or word.endswith("n't"):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def negate_sequence(text):
    text = text.split()
    # remove punctuation
    text = [word.strip("?.,!:;") for word in text]
    # Prepend 'not' to each word if the preceeding word contains a negation.
    text = ['not '+word if is_negative(text[i]) else word for i, word in enumerate(text[1:])]
    return text

print negate_sequence("i am not here right now, because i am not good to see that")
```

Comment: example "i am not happy now because, yes" for my code the result will be ['i','am','not','not happy','not now','not because','yes'] as you can see every word after not has negation 'not' 'not happy','not now','not because' but for the word 'yes' the negation 'not' was not been added,  because in my condition he won't add the negation if he found one of this "?.,!:;" so i want to add 'empty space' to my condition so the result will be ['i','am','not','not happy','now','because','yes'] the negation was added only to happy and stopped, i have tried " " an empty quotation but not working thanks